# Redux-form with Reactstrap

Tags: redux-form

Why my code is giving error when i am using reactstrap for redux-form. i have seen many examples but still I am getting error.
[reactstrap for redux form Integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4mb7.png****)

Error Screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryDFz.png)

Comment: my code is   https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4mb7.png**** in 2nd no line  of Q/A

Answer (score 0):

Which version of `redux-form` and `react` are you using?

I got the same error when using `redux-form v8.1.0` and `react v16.1.1`.

`redux-form` started using context API since `v8.0.0` and context API is introduced in `react v16.3.0`

Check the changelog of redux-form here [redux-form changelog](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/releases)